# Downloading file using webclient results in "Access to the path denied is denied"

Tags: asp.net, webclient

i have button, on a click of which i want to download the file on the local pc, i am using webclient.downloadfile(), but i am getting the below error:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\ms-banner.gif' is denied.
```

i am using below code to download file:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/ms-banner.gif"), "ms-banner.gif");
```

i dont understand why its fetching the file from local server, as i have already stated the remote uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fetching the file from the remote server but trying to save it in the current directory because you have only specified a relative filename as second argument: `"ms-banner.gif"`. And it seems that the account you are running your application under doesn't have permission to write to the current working directory which happens to be `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv`.

So you have basically 2 possibilities:

- Modify the account you are running your application under and grant it permissions to write to this directory
- Specify another location (as an absolute path) to save the file to where the account you are running your application under has write permissions.

Comment: +1 - I think he should be specifying a proper directly, not blindly shoving stuff into Windows.

Comment: i have 2 domains say abc.com and xyz.com, both on the same server, both poiting to same folder in IIS, now i have a file in that directory, if user hits the abc.com and click on download button then file should download from xyz.com domain, what could be the best way to do the same.

Comment: @Abbas, in your ASP.NET application you could use the Request.Url property to fetch the current request url. From there on, you could extract the domain and append the necessary bits to reach the file you want to download.

Comment: the url to download the file is static url, i mean xyz.com/download/filename.pdf, what could be the code to download the file to clients machine, for eg like xls export.

Comment: `client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://xyz.com/download/filename.pdf"), "c:\path\to\wherever\you\want\to\store\the\file\filename.pdf");`

Comment: Hi Darin, we have two domains on the same server pointed to the same directory in IIS.
When a user downloads the file from abc.com/download/abc.pdf, by clicking on the download button, we want the fetch the file from xyz.com instead. Hence on the download click do change the domain from abc.com to xyz.com. 

We are doing this, so that we can reduce the load on the app pool of abc.com.

However, when we download the file, the file downloaded is corrupt. However, when we try to open the file (xyx.com/downloads/file.pdf) from a browser, it displays the pdf correctly.

Comment: Also, when downloading this file, it should display a Save As dialog box for client, to save in his local machine. This is happening right now, only the file which gets downloaded is corrupt.

Comment: We have two domains, htmagazine, vsr.

You can try downloading using the given url 
(Username : p.addhenki1113@auxanotech.com
 Password : 08876)
http://htmagazine.dev.asentechdev.com/User-Registration/Downloads.aspx?ubctid=2&GUID=091189b4-a921-4df0-a9b3-3539790885e9&channel=821&documentID=75900

On the download click button, we have used WebClient to download the file from http://vsr.dev.asentechdev.com/09/091189b4-a921-4df0-a9b3-3539790885e9.pdf, however the file gets downloaded in corrupt format.

Answer (score 0):

contoso.com redirects to microsoft.com... the path you have there in the URL does not exist and you won't be able to download it. I'm not sure why it's trying to go to your local machine, but have you tried some *other* image on some other website? Like http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.gif for example?

Comment: i have 2 domains say abc.com and xyz.com, both on the same server, both poiting to same folder in IIS, now i have a file in that directory, if user hits the abc.com and click on download button then file should download from xyz.com domain, what could be the best way to do the same.